# Evaluate ruby code inside html :css filter

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to add some css style that I calculate in my ruby code within a `haml` template.

I understand that I should use the `:css` filter to add a `style` tag for my css like this:

```
%head
  - my_color = "#0000ff"
  :css
    .my-class { 
      / how can I set my_color here:
      background-color: red; 
    }
```

But how can I use my_color inside the filter?

Edit: To be clear, I am looking for a `<style>` tag, not inline css on an element.

Comment: Do you mean a `<style>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interpolate the variable with `#{my_color}`:

```
- my_color = "#0000ff"
:css
 .my-class {
   background-color: #{my_color};
 }
```

Comment: Thanks – so the block under :css is just regarded as a string from ruby's vantage point.

Comment: Not really. `:css` is an example of a filter in Haml. "The colon character designates a filter. This allows you to pass an indented block of text as input to another filtering program and add the result to the output of Haml.". Here you're doing variable interpolation (in the Haml parser) before passing the string into the filter.  https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#filters